# Fluent Assertion - Tuples

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tuples, fluent-assertions

Is there a way for asserting Tuples using Fluent Assertions?

```
var t1 = new Tuple<Guid, IEnumerable<Guid>>(Guid.Parse("{DA18B047-2F62-45F0-A437-748976B41D22}"),
    new [] { Guid.Parse("{DA18B047-2F62-45F0-A437-748976B41D22}") });

var t2 = new Tuple<Guid, IEnumerable<Guid>>(Guid.Parse("{DA18B047-2F62-45F0-A437-748976B41D22}"),
    new[] { Guid.Parse("{DA18B047-2F62-45F0-A437-748976B41D22}") });
```

This is asserted using either of the following:

```
t1.Should().ShouldBeEquivalentTo(t2);
t1.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(t2);
```

Results in:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException : Expected item[0] to be (da18b047-2f62-45f0-a437-748976b41d22, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]), but found (da18b047-2f62-45f0-a437-748976b41d22, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]).

Expected item[1] to be (119d681c-9171-4ecd-86b6-3b4417ad167c, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]), but found (119d681c-9171-4ecd-86b6-3b4417ad167c, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]).
```

I have also tried:

```
t1.Should().Be(t2);
```

Also, I am not to bothered about the order of Guids either.

**Update**

I am currently using 4.1.1 for this.  Upgrading to 4.19.4 yields the same result.

I have also tried in v5 pre-release using:

```
t1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(t2);
```

Comment: I have a feeling this relates to [this bug](https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/544).

Comment: Nope. It is not related. A tuple implements `Equals` by comparing the individual types in that tulpe using `Equals`. Since one of the types is an `IEnumerable<T>`, this is never going to work.

Comment: I guess the comment above should be the accepted answer?  I went with just using anonymous types for my scenario in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Use `t1.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(t2)` if you use 4.x. If you use 5.x, use `t1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(t2)`.

Comment: Thanks Dennis.  Just updated the question with a bit more info as to what I was doing and have tried.

Comment: In the final release, I've decided to deal with tuples in a specific way. https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/commit/530de04c6dc2c109434b191c0c9544bf04606b91